# Is it possible to save and load JavaScript or Stylesheet (CSS) to/from browser's local db?

Tags: javascript, css, http, caching, browser

We're trying to maximize the performance of our web architecture. We're developing a special way of creating Angular applications, that is based on loading UMD files in old web school by adding them to the head section of a web page:

```
<script src='/scripts/thirdParties/coreUmd.js'></script>
```

Of course one barrier to this architecture is the amount of bytes we need to send to the client on each request.

We know about HTTP caching and how it works. Yet for other reasons we thought about controlling the caching imperatively through code, rather than declaratively through HTTP headers.

We thought of new technologies coming into the browser for storing local data, and we're not very familiar with them. **Local Storage**, **Session Storage**, **Indexed DB** can be seen in Chrome's Developer Tools.

The question is, can we store some `js` and `css` files on the browser, and on next requests load them from browser's storage imperatively to reduce the required bandwidth?

Comment: Yes - FSVO. See data-URIs, eg.. However.. *this probably isn't a / the correct "problem to solve"*.. as browser caching takes care of .. caching. There are numerous additional existing "non-tricky" and "proven" methods to reduce initial and subsequent resource loads: module packaging, HTTP compression, demand/async loading, CDNs, appropriate cache control headers..

Comment: Is the requirement to make only one request to the server for the resources which will be served from the browser following the initial request by the user?

Comment: @guest271314, you go to home page, and an HTML document loads with a small loader script. That script loads really fast, and checks the browser storage for a list of given `js` and `css` files. If they exists, appropriate tags would be inserted into the header section to load them from storage. Otherwise they will be loaded from somewhere (CDN maybe) and will be stored for future operations. This process happens on each complete load. For SPA other requests are not important.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli Yes, that process is possible. What issues are you having implementing the code?

Comment: No issues. I just couldn't find anything on Google. I tried *storing and retrieving JavaScript in/from browser* and no relevant result. I couldn't find relevant results changing keywords many times, so I had to ask.

Comment: @guest271314, can you provide a simple example?

Comment: See [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely one can save and load javascript files from localstorage or session storage.
But that would incur few tweaks:

1. You would need a container javascript file that would be responsible to load or save other files to be cached.
2. There would be scoping issues that would required to be handled with care.

Therefore instead of going with this approach, you can use **manifest file** and enjoy the privileges of **App cache** that browser provides you of its own.